# Docker containers-communication

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a question regarding docker images, containers.

I made 2 images: 1 from my Frontend UI and another from Rest-api(mock server).
Rest-api has an offered port that UI is watching. If I run the rest-api container from docker then `npm start` the UI in visual studio code it works, on localhost I can see the UI with the mock data.
Lets stop this localhost UI run and start the UI container, if I open in the browser the request 404 Not Found. It seems like it can't access or not even watching the mock-server port.
I am not sure what I done wrong or how to do it properly.

For future plan I'd like to achieve to have a backend container and db with the real data and connect the UI container to those, so as I work on the UI I can easily build a new images with the UI changes and check them with real backend data not mock data.

For now I'd like to connect to the mock to see it work at least.

Frontend UI if runs from VS Code it is by default localhost:3000 and it listens to the localhost:2107 port which is the mock-server.
I have Docker Desktop from there I can run both container, but it seems the 2 container can't communicate with each other. If I only run the mock server container and the UI I start locally from my code editor it works, I don't have to start the mock server from code editor as well. My local UI picks up the docker container mock server 2107 port.
When I try to do the same with the UI container, run it open in the browser it gives the error component which is an Unhandled API screen. So UI container runs as well it just doesn't seem to listen to the 2107 mock api port.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], describing more specifically how you're starting the container, what URLs you're connecting to, and which "localhost" works (the host system, the frontend container, the backend container are all separately "localhost")?

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated the question with port details. I also read things about 8080:80 docker ports and stuff, but not sure about those.. Also read about docker-compose a bit, maybe my dockerfile or nginx file doesn't described well, or proxy required in the docker file? not entirely sure where it goes off.